# Hive split pattern using regex

Tags: sql, regex, database, hive

I have a problem with split pattern in hive query.
sample string from the table:

```
['EN', 'FR', 'DE', 'IT', 'JA', 'RU', 'ZH', 'ES', 'ZH']
```

and now with the split function I would like to return this string in this way:

```
EN  
FR  
...  
ZH
```

at first I tried this way: `split(data.language, ',')[1]`
I don't know how I can get rid of square brackets and quotation marks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **`regexp_replace`** to replace `[|]|'` characters then **`split`** the string column then **`explode`** the array.

```
select explode(split(regexp_replace(sample,"[\\[|\\'|\\]]",""),",")) 
   from (
select string("['EN', 'FR', 'DE', 'IT', 'JA', 'RU', 'ZH', 'ES', 'ZH']")as sample
     )e;

--output
--+---+
--|col|
--+---+
--| EN|
--| FR|
--| DE|
--| IT|
--| JA|
--| RU|
--| ZH|
--| ES|
--| ZH|
--+---+
```

Comment: If I have a poem that has a category and this word list, I can get that effect:  
--+---+-----------+
--|col|category |
--+----------------+
--|EN| GAMES |
--|FR| GAMES |
...